# Elasticsearch "Begin with" full words

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents in my elastic search index
#1: names: John Doe, Jimmy Smiths
#2: names: John Williams

I'm trying to work out a query that can help me to match the first names or full name, the rules are:

1. if the input is John, then the query should return doc #1 and #2
2. if the input is Jimmy, then the query should return me doc #1
3. if the input is Doe, then the query should return me nothing
4. if the input is John Williams, then the query should return me doc #2
5. if the input is John Jim, then the query should return me nothing

Any kind of help is appreciated.

I have tried keyword match and match_phrase_prefix, but they all not working as I expected

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `names` field?

Comment: It can be either a keyword or a text field, I haven't decided which one to use yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can use a `keyword` field and the `prefix` query, like this:

```
POST test/_doc
{
  "names": ["John Doe", "Jimmy Smiths"]
}
POST test/_doc
{
  "names": ["John Williams"]
}

# Returns both docs
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "names.keyword": {
        "value": "John",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

# Returns first doc
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "names.keyword": {
        "value": "Jimmy",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

# Returns nothing
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "names.keyword": {
        "value": "Doe",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

# Returns second doc
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "names.keyword": {
        "value": "John Williams",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}

# Returns nothing
POST test/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "names.keyword": {
        "value": "John Jim",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```